# Laravel file upload required validation firing even when file is present

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form, one field is for a file named `attachment`, in my request the validation for this field requires it to be present when another field named `requestType` is set to the value of `sick` by using the `required_if` validation rule.

The issue I'm facing is that even when I upload a file for the input field in question the validation rule from the request class still gets triggered: `The attachment field is required when request type is sick.`

Here's my code:

Please note that the html `required` attribute on the `attachment` field is not what is causing the issue, on the page load it's set to `disabled` and when `requestType` is set to sick the `disabled` attribute is removed.

**View**

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'employee.request.store', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '', 'files' => 'true']) !!}

            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->first('requestType', 'has-error') }}">
                <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> {{ Lang::get('employee_request_contractor_create.request_type') }} *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    {!! 
                        Form::select('requestType', 
                            ['' => 'Select', 'normal' => 'Normal', 'emergency' => 'Emergency', 'sick' => 'Sick'], 
                            '', 
                            ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'requestType', 'required' => 'required']
                        ) 
                    !!}
                </div>
                {!! $errors->first('requestType', '<label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="">:message</label>') !!}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->first('attachment', 'has-error') }}" id="attachmentFormGroup">
                <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> {{ Lang::get('employee_request_contractor_create.attachment') }} <small>(Sick only)</small> </label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" required="required">
                    <label>(Please provide HR with original copy)</label>
                </div>
                {!! $errors->first('attachment', '<label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="">:message</label>') !!}
            </div>
    <!-- other form inputs and submit button -->
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Request**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'requestType'   => 'required|max:255',
        'attachment'    => 'required_if:requestType,sick|mimes:pdf,jpg,png,gif,jpeg|max:512',
        /* other rules */
    ];

}
```

If I remove `required_if:requestType` the attachment uploads just fine and if I output in my controller:

```
if(\Input::hasFile('attachment') echo 'true';
```

I will see true.

When I dd($request) in my controller store method I see the following (relevant parts):

```
+request: ParameterBag {#227 ▼
    #parameters: array:10 [▼
      "_token" => "XkQwP608M5WQ4qtHCYN0dIVETDeqzL0E5ZI99iSf"
      "requestType" => "sick"
      "manager" => "2"
      "dateFrom" => "01-06-2015"
      "dateFromHijri" => "1436-08-14"
      "dateTo" => "02-06-2015"
      "dateToHijri" => "1436-08-15"
      "noOfDays" => "2"
      "location" => "London"
      "contactNumber" => "123456"
    ]
}
```

and...

```
+files: FileBag {#221 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "attachment" => UploadedFile {#27 ▼
        -test: false
        -originalName: "test_doc.pdf"
        -mimeType: "application/pdf"
        -size: 82584
        -error: 0
      }
    ]
  }
```

Is the rule getting fired because attachment is not showing up along with the other request attributes?

Update: Error messages:

```
["errors"]=>
  object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)#178 (1) {
    ["bags":protected]=>
    array(1) {
      ["default"]=>
      object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)#179 (2) {
        ["messages":protected]=>
        array(1) {
          ["attachment"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            string(59) "The attachment field is required when request type is sick."
          }
        }
        ["format":protected]=>
        string(8) ":message"
      }
    }
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `$validator->failed()`? That will give you a list per validation rule.

Comment: See update, I added in the error bag from the session as not using a validator instance but rather the Middleware for validation. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to remove the quotes around 'true' in your form open line. You should set this as a boolean, not a string.

Comment: @JanWillem how would that affect the validator?

Comment: That will set the files param to true, which means adding enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form tag.

Comment: I will give it a shot, thanks!

Comment: Why your `attachment` input is not in `$request` object?

Answer (score 5):

Since the input is disabled when the `requestType` is not set to `sick`, the attachment is not included in the `POST` request sent to server. That is why Laravel's Request validation file triggers, because it doesn't even see the value in the `POST` data. To solve that, just add `sometimes` in the validation string for the `attachment` filed. The code should look like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'requestType'   => 'required|max:255',
        'attachment'    => 'sometimes|required_if:requestType,sick|mimes:pdf,jpg,png,gif,jpeg|max:512',
        /* other rules */
    ];

}
```

---

Here is an excerpt from the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-when-present) regarding this issue:

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the data being validated. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list:
>
> ```
> $v = Validator::make($data, [
>
>    'email' => 'sometimes|required|email',
>
> ]);
> ```
>
> In the example above, the email field will only be validated if it is present in the $data array.