# Problems with uploading some of PDF files in Laravel 5

Tags: pdf, file-upload, laravel-5, mime-types

I have an application based on Laravel 5 with file upload functionality. Everything works fine except uploading of some PDF files.

The applications can not upload some of PDF files, and when I try to open them, they seems normal like any other PDF files. Any idea how to solve this problem?

```
 dd($request);  //MyRequest $request

// Here is the part of dd function related to file

 +files: FileBag {#244 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "file" => UploadedFile {#27 ▼
        -test: false
        -originalName: "111.pdf"
        -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
        -size: 0
        -error: 1
      }]}
//Here is my request rules
 return ['file'  =>  'mimes:pdf|max:10000',
```

While for other PDF files are just working fine like bellow dd($request)

```
+files: FileBag {#244 ▼
#parameters: array:1 [▼
  "file" => UploadedFile {#27 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "cv.pdf"
    -mimeType: "application/pdf"
    -size: 28141
    -error: 0
  }]}
```

Comment: So you're saying the first type doesn't upload?

Comment: Yes, it gives application/octet-stream as mimeType.

Comment: How were the PDFs that show as `application/octet-stream` created? Can you open them in PDF software such as adobe or foxit? I believe it's a different kind of file but I'm unsure hopefully someone with more experience can give their input. Also, what is the error that occurs when you try to upload the file that shows as `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: Yes I can open them like a normal PDF file in adobe reader. The error is that it can not upload the file, when I give required as a rule it always give file is required which means it is not uploaded, and when I remove the required rule then it gives has no file to true.. It's a weird problem really..

Comment: Do you have the problem with normal pdfs also. I've encountered this issue for normal pdfs and had to rely on html `required` attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119795/laravel-file-upload-required-validation-firing-even-when-file-is-present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error value `1` is defined as [UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). Which simply means that the uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in the php.ini.

Your problem is not related to the mime type.

Comment: You got it, the problem solved well done, Thanks @Setasign ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, ain't know why Laravel doesn't show the error In request object...